# MySqlConnection throws me 3 exceptions all call its Open( ) method

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, exception

I have a strange problem with MySQL.

First of all, I clarify that this is my commonly used connection string: `"Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=<my_password>;SslMode=None;Port=3307;Database=TestDB"`

In fact, I finished a project in `C#` that was perfectly connected to MySql, the problem came when I started a new project and did the corresponding import of `MySql.Data.dll`

I always try my code, so I decided to test MySql connection using the following methods:

```
var mysql = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=<my_password>;SslMode=None;Port=3307;Database=TestDB");
mysql.Open();
```

---

```
var mysql = new MySqlConnection();
mysql.ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=<my_password>;SslMode=None;Port=3307;Database=TestDB";
mysql.Open();
```

But he always throws me these 3 exceptions:

> Exception 1 of 3
>
> **System.TypeInitializationException:** `'An exception occurred in the type >initializer of' MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager '.'`
>
> `TypeInitializationException: An exception occurred in the type initializer of 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration'.`

---

> Exception 2 of 3
>
> **System.TypeInitializationException:** `'An exception occurred in the type >initializer of' MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager '.'`
>
> `ConfigurationErrorsException: Error in the initialization of the configuration system`

---

> Exception 3 of 3
>
> **System.TypeInitializationException:** `'An exception occurred in the type >initializer of' MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager '.'`
>
> `ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration section unrecognized userSettings.`

I do not understand what happens, since my previous project that uses the same connection method connects without problem.

What is this about?

Do I have to delete the current project and start it from the beginning?

Comment: This seems to be related to your config file. Perhaps you have something wrong there.

Comment: @Steve But my previous application connects without problem

Comment: New project, new problems.  What the last one did really doesn't matter.